# Can I access the visual voicemail files on the iphone thru the SDK?

Tags: iphone, sdk

I would like to access the visual voicemail files that are stored on an iphone.  Are there ways to access these files through the SDK?  Does anybody have any experience in working with these files?  I am assuming that they are files that are downloaded from the network and stored locally on the iphone.

Answer (score 2):

No, each application on the iPhone is isolated, so you cannot access data for any other application, unless Apple specifically provides an API for doing so, like they did for the Contacts list.

Answer (score 2):

No - the issue is that Apple provides very few methods to access data outside of your application's "sandbox".  At this point, you can really only access contacts data and the camera via the supported methods.  If you try to access data outside of your application without using an Apple provided public API designed for that purpose, your app will most likely not be allowed in the app store.  Maybe this will change in the future, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: Probably not. The sandbox was broken in 2.0, but fixed in 2.1. See the last paragraph at http://arstechnica.com/journals/apple.ars/2008/09/12/iphone-2-1-fixes-passcode-lock-exploit-other-security-holes