# Accessing voicemail in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

Is there any way to access the voicemail from the SDK. As I know this cannot be done. At least in the new SDK have they given any control over it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I access the visual voicemail files on the iphone thru the SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405808/can-i-access-the-visual-voicemail-files-on-the-iphone-thru-the-sdk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not be able to directly access the voicemail from your app, but several operators provide a direct call number for people to dial directly into their voicemail.

You could then have people enter this voicemail number in the preferences and access it using a url like `tel:1-408-555-5555`

More information about this in the [iOS Reference Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007893-SW1)

Comment: Thank you Claus for the reply

Answer (score 1):

Correct, this cannot be done from the SDK.