# How to receive the voice mails in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone-4

How to receive the voice mails in iphone sdk? I want to access the voice mails in my iphone application. But I don't have the idea about voice mail receiving and sending from iphone sdk. So please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing voicemail in iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948565/accessing-voicemail-in-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't there is no API call for this in the iOS SDK. Also apple will not allow it.

Comment: How to receive the phone calls in iphone sdk